How to view the springboot logs stored on s3 bucket using loki promtail EKS
After enabling the loki on EKS with S3 storage, the folders (fake, index, loki_cluster_seed.json) are created inside the s3 bucket . What is this folders related to? Is there any clear explaination on how to view the application logs stored on the s3 bucket?
What this each folder consists & how the logs are stored as chunks to s3 bucket & how to view the logs inside s3 bucket or else how to convert it to human readable format:


Hey there and welcome on StackOverflow. You question is not quite related to programming and thus it doesn't fully fit here. Next time, please use https://serverfault.com to get a better audience.
However, let me answer your question.
Promtail is a component that collects logs from pods and sends them to Loki, which stores logs in a dedicated S3 bucket in special formats and structures as you already discovered.
This structure is not intended to be readable by a user directly. You need one other component - Grafana, which provides a web interface to retrieve these logs and potentially visualize them, see docs.

Thank you for the response given. Yes I have already added the datasource on the grafana & i am getting the logs of each pod on different namespace level.
My only problem is for how many hours the logs will be shown lively. If i want the previous logs to view, whether it is visible. Is there any option to save the old logs onto to storage?

You can't just upload directly additional logs into S3 bucket. They need to go through Loki component. Please, kindly check the upstream documentation about Loki to understand how it works. For example this article about retention - https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/
